# Why did Talia Al'Gul have to forgive her father?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

In the scene in *The Dark Knight Rises* where

> Miranda Tate confesses to Batman that she is Talia Al'Gul,

she says something about her finally forgiving her father when he died. Why did she have to forgive her father in the first place? And did she willingly leave the League of Shadows or did they banish her along with Bane?

Comment: CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach - Can you please avoid spamming the board with tag edits. 5 per day is the accepted volume, not 10+

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Talia resented Ra's Al Ghul because he excommunicated Bane.

> Ra's Al Ghul excommunicated Bane because he reminded him too much of his wife, Talia's mother, and the prison she was kept in because of him.  Talia loved Bane (in a fatherly sort of way), and so when he was excommunicated, Talia acquired a resentment towards her father that did not pass until his death.

When Bane was excommunicated, Talia left with him.  Because they still maintained the ideals of the League of Shadows, they became the heads to fulfill Ra's legacy after he died.

Comment: So all that stuff Alfred says about Bane being too extreme for even the League of Shadows are just unfounded rumors?

Comment: I always took that as his speculation.  No one knew the real reason he was excommunicated until Talia told Bruce.

Comment: I watched the movie again and Talia makes it pretty clear that what you said is right :)

Comment: Thanks for the validation :) I had already seen the movie a couple of times when I wrote the answer, so it was still fresh in my mind.  Also, I'm in love with Marion Cotillard and never miss a single word she says...

Comment: If I were a guy, I'd be in love with her too :)

Answer (score 7):

Within the context of the movie Talia is referring to the fact that:

> Her father left her mother when she was pregnant with her. And her mother ended up the one who was imprisoned for her father's mercenary work. Talia was left to grow up in the pit with only Bane as her protector.

As far as if Talia was banished with Bane the movie isn't clear. But Bane does make a point to say that since Ra's Al Ghul is dead, he is the League of Shadows.

> (really Talia is leading it)