# Why was Bane excommunicated from the League of Shadows?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

In *The Dark Knight Rises* we know that Bane has been excommunicated from the League of Shadows. Considering that Bane protected Ra's al Ghul's daughter [Talia al Ghul](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Talia_al_Ghul_(Marion_Cotillard)) while in prison, why did Ra's al Ghul not protect Bane in the League of Shadows?

Who had Bane ousted and why?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21273/why-did-talia-algul-have-to-forgive-her-father?rq=1

Comment: For failing to pay his subscription fees.

Comment: Maybe they had something against asthmatics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bane was a constant reminder to Ra's of the hellish torment and death that his wife suffered in the prison. Ra's was also uncomfortable about Bane's love for, and protective nature around, Talia.

For those reasons, Ra's himself had Bane excommunicated.

**Source provided by Ben Osborne, [The Dark Knight Rises script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Dark-Knight-Rises,-The.html).**

> [Ra's Al Ghul] saw only a monster who could
>              never be tamed. Whose very
>              existence was a reminder of the
>              hell he'd left his wife to die in.
>              He excommunicated Bane from the
>              League of Shadows. [Bane's] only crime
>              was that he loved me. I could not
>              truly forgive my father...
>              Until [Batman] murdered him.

Comment: Are there Any Sources ??

Comment: @KyloRen See the script at http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Dark-Knight-Rises,-The.html, pages 149-149. Talia says, "[Ra's al Ghul] saw only a monster who could never be tamed. Whose very existence was a reminder of the hell he'd left his wife to die in. He excommunicated Bane from the League of Shadows. His only crime was that he loved me."